# Android Full screen notification

Tags: android, notifications, dialog

I want to design a bootstrap module that sets full screen notifications, but I currently don't find how to set full screen notifications.
Just like when the app is launched for the first time, it will tell the user whether they agree to turn on notification permissions.
Is a full-screen notification a floating notification?

what should I do?
Thank you in advance to everyone who answered!